# Angular Route to Lazy Module Causes Redirect

Tags: angular, redirect, routes, lazy-loading

I have an Angular2 app with simple routing.  The route looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'detail', outlet: 'primary', component: DetailComponent },
    { path: 'user', outlet: 'primary', loadChildren: 'app/auth/auth.module#AuthModule' },
    { path: '',   redirectTo: '/user/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Now, this works great, but I want to lazy load the detail module.  If I set the detail module up as lazy loaded, however, I get a redirect to `/user/login`.  To lazy load, I simply do:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'detail', outlet: 'primary', loadChildren: 'app/detail/detail.module#DetailModule' },
    { path: 'user', outlet: 'primary', loadChildren: 'app/auth/auth.module#AuthModule' },
    { path: '',   redirectTo: '/user/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

The routing trace gives this output when run with the above:

```
Router Event: t
NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/detail')
t {id: 1, url: "/detail"}
App detail
Router Event: t
RoutesRecognized(id: 1, url: '/detail', urlAfterRedirects: '/user/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'user', path:'user') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') }  }  } )
t {id: 1, url: "/detail", urlAfterRedirects: "/user/login", state: e}
Router Event: t
NavigationCancel(id: 1, url: '/detail')
t {id: 1, url: "/detail", reason: ""}
Router Event: t
NavigationStart(id: 2, url: '/detail')
t {id: 2, url: "/detail"}
Router Event: t
RoutesRecognized(id: 2, url: '/detail', urlAfterRedirects: '/user/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'user', path:'user') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') }  }  } )
t {id: 2, url: "/detail", urlAfterRedirects: "/user/login", state: e}
Router Event: t
NavigationEnd(id: 2, url: '/detail', urlAfterRedirects: '/user/login')
t {id: 2, url: "/detail", urlAfterRedirects: "/user/login"}
```

Eventually, this leads to a `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

Thanks,
Lee

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears that you can't lazy load a module in that way unless it has it's own routing.  So, simply create a routing module and associate it with the lazy module, such as:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DetailComponent } from './detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DetailComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class DetailRoutingModule {}
```

And hooking it up with:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DetailRoutingModule } from './detail-routing.module';
import { DetailComponent } from './detail.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [FormsModule, CommonModule, DetailRoutingModule],
  declarations: [DetailComponent],
  exports: [DetailComponent, CommonModule]
})
export class DetailModule{}
```

Lee